# Data disappearing when travelling to another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, queue

I am trying to make program which simulates a waitingline and lift, and individual skiers.
Now my output is fine and as expected until the skiers hit the top of the lift then begin to ski, which is when the threads begin. 
My problem is, once a skier is finished he should then pend himself back into the waiting line, but alot of the skiers go missing, and never return to the line.

Any ideas?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;



public class ThreadsAssignment {

    // Declare and initalise queues and arrays
    public static BlockingQueue<String> liftQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>(11);
    public static BlockingQueue<String> waitQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();
    public static String toLift;
    public static String toWait;
    public static String liftFront = "EMPTY";
    public static String waitFront;
    public static int populatedLift = 0;
    public static int pauseLift;
    public static int slopeTime;
    public static String toPend;
    public static int queueSize;




    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{


        // fill both queues list for startup
        for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
            waitQueue.add(Integer.toString(i));
        }       
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            liftQueue.add("EMPTY");
        }

        // loop the simulation
        while(true){

            System.out.println("In Queue " + "(" + waitQueue.size() + "): " + waitQueue);
            System.out.println("On Lift " + "(" + populatedLift + "): " + liftQueue + "\n");

            // Stop lift for 1 second
            try{
                Thread.sleep(1000);} 
            catch (InterruptedException ex) {}

            // test if the lift stops
            if ((Math.random() * 100) >= 95) {
                Random rand = new Random();
                pauseLift = rand.nextInt(8001);

                System.out.println("Lift paused for " + pauseLift + " milliseconds");

                try{Thread.sleep(pauseLift);}
                catch (InterruptedException ex){}}
            else{}




            // get the head of the waiting line then add it to lift, check if any skier is waiting.
            liftFront = liftQueue.peek();

            if (waitQueue.size() == 0){
                liftQueue.add("EMPTY"); 
            }
            else{
                toLift = waitQueue.take();
                liftQueue.add(toLift);
                populatedLift++;
            }

            // if the front of the liftQueue is occupied, call a new skier thread
            if (liftFront.equals("EMPTY")){
                liftQueue.poll();}
            else{ 
                liftQueue.poll();
                populatedLift--;
                skier s = new skier(liftFront, waitQueue);
                new Thread(s).start();
            }


        }
    }

    // skier thread         
    public static class skier extends Thread {
        static String name;
        static BlockingQueue<String> theQueue;

        // Constructor for the thread
        public skier(String name, BlockingQueue<String> theQueue){
            skier.name = name;
            skier.theQueue = theQueue;

        }

        // run method that makes random skiing time then pends the skier back into the queue
        @Override public void run() {
            toPend = skier.name;
            Random speed = new Random();
            slopeTime = speed.nextInt(10001) + 2000;


            try {Thread.sleep(slopeTime);}
            catch (InterruptedException ex){}

            currentThread.
            if (waitQueue.contains(toPend)){}
            else {try {
                waitQueue.put(toPend);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){}
            System.out.println(toPend + "has been pended");}
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code may cause skiers to become missing:

```
static String name;
static BlockingQueue<String> theQueue;
```

`static` means that all instances of `skier` will share last submitted name. You must make all skiers keep their names to themselves:

```
final String name;
final BlockingQueue<String> theQueue; // this may be left `static` since there's only one instance, but this would be unclean code.
// Or, as an option, let `skier` instances re-use outer class `queue`.
```

Btw, Java has convention of starting class names with upper-case letter, so it should be `Skier` as well.

And you don't need `EMPTY` constant, just call `queue.isEmpty()`